# Jest: fake setInterval not working as expected

Tags: reactjs, timer, jestjs

I'm trying to create a Timer component, that allows children to start a timer, and then provides them with how much time is left in 1 second intervals.

I have the following test:

[Full Code](https://github.com/NirBenita/todo-pomo/blob/test-timer/src/App.test.tsx#L82)

```js
/* Test */
jest.useFakeTimers()
it.only('should update the reamining time every second', () => {
  const time = 1/12
  const wrapper = shallow(<Timer time={time} />)

  wrapper.find('.start').simulate('click')

  jest.runAllTimers()    

  expect(setInterval.mock.calls.length).toBe(4)
})
```

[Full Code](https://github.com/NirBenita/todo-pomo/blob/test-timer/src/components/Timer.tsx#L29)

```js
/*    Code     */

updateTimeLeft() {
  const now: number = +new Date()
  const timeLeft = this.state.endTime - now

  if (timeLeft < 0) {
    clearInterval(this.state.timeInterval)
  }
  
  this.setState({ timeLeft })
}

intializeTimer(minutes: number) {
  const startTime: number = new Date().getTime()
  const endTime: number = new Date(startTime + minutes * 60 * 1000).getTime()

  this.setState({
    startTime,
    endTime
  })

  const timeInterval: NodeJS.Timer = global.setInterval(
    () => this.updateTimeLeft(),
    1000
  )
  this.setState({ timeInterval })
}
```

The code works. The problem is, in the test, `setInteval.mock.calls.length = 1`, not matter what.

Is there anything I misunderstood about Jest fake timers?

Thank you ❤️

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing with fake timers. 
You have called setInterval inside initializeTimer only once, that's why setInterval.mock.calls.length shows you 1. But it's callback function will be called as much as you need.
Think of it as for loop, you have only one for loop declaration (our setInterval in this case), and as much body calls as you need (our callback function here)

Hope, it helps.